Kid token issue with upgrade from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 8
Recently upgraded a project from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 8, and the way we generate bearer tokens - particularly validate them - is failing.
Here is the code that previously worked:
var appSettings = Configuration.GetSection("AuthSettings").Get<AuthSettings>();
var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.S);

services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = true
                };
            });


using System;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using Acme.Services.Api.Code.Settings;
using Acme.Services.Core;
using Acme.Services.Core.Repository;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

namespace Acme.Services.Api.Controllers
{
    public interface ITokenHandler
    {
        string GenerateToken(string[] roles, int userId, int daysOffset);
        string SlideToken(string replace, out DateTime expires);
    }

    public class TokenHandler : ITokenHandler
    {
        private readonly ISettingsRepository _settingsRepository;
        private readonly AuthSettings _authSettings;

        public TokenHandler(IOptions<AuthSettings> authSettings, ISettingsRepository settingsRepository)
        {
            _settingsRepository = settingsRepository;
            _authSettings = authSettings.Value;
        }

        public string GenerateToken(string[] roles, int userId, int daysOffset)
        {
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_authSettings.S);
                    
            var claims = roles.Select(x => new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, x)).ToList();
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userId.ToString()));
                    
            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
                    {
                        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
                        Expires =  GetExpiryDateMinutes().AddDays(daysOffset),
                        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
                    };

            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

            return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
        }
                
        public string SlideToken(string tokenValue, out DateTime expires)
        {
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_authSettings.S);

            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var validations = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                        ValidateAudience = false,
                        ValidateLifetime = false
                    };
                            
            ClaimsPrincipal claims = handler.ValidateToken(tokenValue, validations, out var tokenSecure);

            expires = GetExpiryDateMinutes();
                    
            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
                    {
                        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims.Claims),
                        Expires = expires,
                        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
                    };

            var token = handler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

            return handler.WriteToken(token);
        }
                
        private DateTime GetExpiryDateMinutes()
        {
            var date =  DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(int.Parse(_settingsRepository.GetByNameAllowNull("TokenExpiryInMinutes")?.Value ??  "30"));
            return date;
        }
    }
}

And here is the error I get:

Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException: IDX10517: Signature validation failed. The token's kid is missing. Keys tried: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey, KeyId: '', InternalId: 'CPMLsTVgBeiAqC-MBrp6XPSJEfX2rM9anuEqZHauImw'. , KeyId:
'. Number of keys in TokenValidationParameters: '1'.
Number of keys in Configuration: '0'.
Exceptions caught:
'[PII of type 'System.String' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
Token: '[PII of type 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'. See https://aka.ms/IDX10503 for details.
at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateSignature(String token, JwtSecurityToken jwtToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, BaseConfiguration configuration)
at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateSignatureAndIssuerSecurityKey(String token, JwtSecurityToken jwtToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, BaseConfiguration configuration)
at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateJWS(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, BaseConfiguration currentConfiguration, SecurityToken& signatureValidatedToken, ExceptionDispatchInfo& exceptionThrown)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(String token, JwtSecurityToken outerToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, SecurityToken& signatureValidatedToken)
at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, SecurityToken& validatedToken)
at Acme.Services.Api.Controllers.TokenHandler.SlideToken(String tokenValue, DateTime& expires) in /Users/mattowens/dev/app-Acme-api-portal/api/Acme.Services.Api/Controllers/TokenHandler.cs:line 66
at Acme.Services.Api.SlidingSessionMiddleware.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0() in /Users/mattowens/dev/app-Acme-api-portal/api/Acme.Services.Api/SlidingSessionMiddleware.cs:line 30
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.g__ProcessEvents|241_0(HttpProtocol protocol, Stack`1 events)

My packages are
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AspNetCore.RouteAnalyzer" Version="0.5.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="13.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Check.Password.Strength" Version="1.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Edi.RouteDebugger" Version="1.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Ical.Net" Version="4.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Karambolo.Extensions.Logging.File" Version="3.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="8.0.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="OfficeOpenXml.Core.ExcelPackage" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="7.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters" Version="8.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Newtonsoft" Version="7.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="8.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="8.0.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="PartialResponse.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json" Version="5.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="9.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="9.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="ValueInjecter" Version="3.2.0" />
</ItemGroup>

Error is thrown on line:
ClaimsPrincipal claims = handler.ValidateToken(tokenValue, validations, out var tokenSecure);

Any help would be hugely appreciated.
Thanks,
KH

Hi @KnowHoper, Check your secret key that you use for generating the token and the hash you pass. In .NET 8, they are more stringent, so you should use the recommended character length. For HmacSha256, Recommended: 32 characters (256 bits).

I'm running into something similar after updating System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt from 8.2.0 to 8.3.0. Can you try downgrading to 8.2.0 to see if it helps you? (That's not the ultimate fix, but it might help point us in the right direction!)
